# No write access to SMB share of windows drive after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, cifs, smb

I used to create a share to my windows directory with a script. I use a script because the windows machine is not always turned on.

```
sudo mount.cifs //muziekserver/muziek /cifs/muziek/ -o user=Aak/,uid=aak
```

I always had full access rights using nautilus. But after upgrading to 11.10 I only have read access. All files are owned by root. Any suggestions how to fix this? Using sudo works, but that ain't a nice solution. btw windows user = 'Aak', userid on the linux is 'aak'

Any help or suggestions appreciated,

Comment: Have you tried unmounting the share and then chown-ing the folder?

Comment: Yes, you probably have to chown the folder like karatedog said, or change the sharing properties. I know that in XP you just right click the folder and find the sharing options, and enable writing to the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html? It has several diagnostic steps that might help you.